# Why the result of this loop is 21?

Tags: python, loops

Anyone can give me a full example of this code? Why the result total is 21 (ie the sum of current) if I print total???

```
end=6
total = 0
current = 1
while current <= end:
    total += current
    current += 1

print total
```

Comment: Why do you think the result wouldn't be 21?

Comment: Because I think to find the sum I need to sum the results of total and not of current. Can you give me a an explanation?

Comment: @Overnet what do you think `total += current` is doing?

Comment: But summing the partial totals would give 1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + (1+2+3+4) + (1+2+3+4+5) + (1+2+3+4+5+6).  For all I know that's what you really want, but it's something different.

Comment: Thanks. I know. To find the result I need to sum the current because total += current ?
It's true?

Answer (score 11):

Because `1+2+3+4+5+6` is `21`. Why is that mysterious?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I don't understand why I sum the results of current and not of total.

Comment: Thanks. I know. To find the result I need to sum the current because total += current ? It's true?

Comment: @Overnet: `total += current` is equivalent (in this context) to `total = total + current`, So in each iteration, you're adding the value of `current` to `total`.

Answer (score 3):

You can usually get to the bottom of this sort of thing by introducing some basic debugging. I have added a print inside the loop of your code so that you can see what is happening after each iteration:

```
end=6
total = 0
current = 1
while current <= end:
    total += current
    current += 1
    print "total: ", total, "\tcurrent: ", current 

print total
```

The output is:

```
total:  1   current:  2
total:  3   current:  3
total:  6   current:  4
total:  10  current:  5
total:  15  current:  6
total:  21  current:  7
21
```

To summaries what is happening here, total and current are initialised to 0 and 1 respectively, on the first loop total is set using `total += current` (which is equivalent to `total = total + current`) i.e. total = 0+1, then current is incremented by 1 to 2 so after the first loop they are 1 & 2 respectively.

On the second loop `total += current` would be evaluated as total = 1+2 (the values as of the end of the previous loop) and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I know. To find the result I need to sum the current because total += current ? It's true?

Comment: @Overnet Sorry, I am not completely clear what you are asking here, I have updated my answer with a further explanation which will hopefully clear things up. Let me know if there is still any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

What have you expect?
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21

here are are the start values and the values of each loop

```
total   0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 10 -> 15 -> 21
current 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 ->  5 ->  6 ->  7
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But the sum of this result is because there is write total += current?

Comment: "total += current" is the same as "total = total + current". I hope that helps you